# Can't edit inputText after setting state [react-native]

Tags: javascript, ios, input, react-native, state

After sending a fetch request, and save in a state data, and display the value saved in the inputText I can't edit it anymore. Otherwise, it works when my input is clear.

Here is the code :

First step I fetch data needed after submiting textInput on `input.js`

```
<TextInput
    style={[ style.itemInfoMajor, global.alignRight ]}
    onFocus={ onFocus }
    onChangeText={ this._onChange }
    onSubmitEditing={ () => this._onSubmit(network) }
    value={ value }
    returnKeyType="done"
    enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={ true }
    clearButtonMode="always"
    placeholder={ network }
    placeholderTextColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)"
    autoCorrect={ false }
    autoCapitalize="none"
    clearTextOnFocus={ true }
/>
```

On `list.js` I retrieve data after loading application.

It there where I set the state who get the value for the `inputText`

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._loadInitialState().done();
},


async _loadInitialState() {
  try {
    const value = await Storage.get('userData');

    if (value !== null) {
      this.setState({
        data: value,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And it's the below where I passed the state to the input component

```
<Input
  onFocus={ this._handleFocus.bind(this, item) }
  value={ value }
  ref={ item }
  key={ i }
  network={ item }
/>
```

I join a little video to watch in live the problem : https://vid.me/8L9k
The source code is here : https://github.com/statiks/statiks-react-native/blob/master/sources/input/index.js

**How can I do to edit this value for this input ?**

Answer (score 2):

Try setting value in getInitialState:

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    ...,
    value: this.props.value
  };
},
```

Then, using this.state.value in the textInput:

```
<TextInput
  ...
  value={ this.state.value }
  ... />
```

Then, update the value state on change:

```
_onChange(username) {
  this.setState({ value: username });
 },
```

It also looks like you may be passing the incorrect value down as a prop. You need to pass this.state.data instead of value:

```
<Input
 value={ this.state.data }
 ref={ item }
 key={ i }
 network={ item }
/>
```

I don't have your complete code, but I tested it and it seems to be working for me this way. (you may need to set an initial state of data on the parent as an empty string or data structure)

Comment: Yes. You are right. There are a couple of more issue, then I saw.

Comment: The complete code is here : https://github.com/statiks/statiks-react-native/blob/master/sources/input/index.js you can also build the projet. Anyway, I didn't have access to `this.props.value` on the `getInitialState` of the `input.js` component.

Comment: Yes, you may need to set the value of `value` in the state of the parent as an empty string until the data is ready

Comment: I tried your idea but it didn't. It appears after I get the data from asyncstorage I can't edit, and before submiting the input and saving in storage I cant edit them

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug in _onChange. Shouldn't it be

```
_onChange(username) {
    this.setState({ username: username });
},
```

Comment: That's just a shortcut if the state/value had the same name.